# How to change assembly name of dll pragmatically using Mono.Cecil?

Tags: c#, .net, mono.cecil

I am new to Cecil class library. Found that documentation is not available for cecil. I now need to change Assembly name of dll given `CashCountingLibrary.dll` to `LibCashCounter.dll`

How can I do it using cecil?

Note : I need to do it pragmatically not by design

Comment: i came across this library studied it well was getting problem because of incomplete knowledge

Comment: pragmatically or programatically?

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you need?

```
var assm = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly("assemblyPath");
assm.Name = new AssemblyNameDefinition("newName", Version.Parse("1.0.0.0"));
assm.Write("newNameAssemblyPath");
```